# Twisted python to read from kafka and write to elasticsearch

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I am new to Twisted, this is my first program.

I can not find a way to use the KafkaConsumer from the kafka-python library and use treq to trigger a post request to elasticsearch.

I could decompose the problem in small pieces:
Create an kafka consumer iterator and read data from it (the topic may be huge)

```
def consumeKafka():
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers="kafka:9092", auto_offset_reset='earliest')
    consumer.subscribe(['kafkapipeline'])
    for v in consumer:
        v.value
```

post to elasticsearch using treq

```
def post(self):
    d = treq.post('http://es:9200/pro/pr/', self.data)
    d.addCallbacks(lambda x: print(x), lambda x: print("error %s " % x))
```

start the reactor

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.callWhenRunning(consumeKafka)
reactor.run()
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Kafka at all, so I'm not sure if this will work for you. Also, I'm assuming your having trouble running Kafka and treq at the same time. A generic way I deal with iterators in Twisted is to use `inlineCallbacks` to wait for a result and then do something with that result afterwards.

```
from twisted.internet import defer

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def consumeKafka():
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers="kafka:9092", auto_offset_reset='earliest')
    consumer.subscribe(['kafkapipeline'])
    for v in consumer:
        value = yield v.value
        # do stuff with value
```

Then you can simply call this function and the reactor will take care of the rest. So your main section will look like this:

```
consumeKafka()
reactor.run()
```

Note that the `consumeKafka()` function returns a `Deferred` so you add callbacks and errbacks as needed. Once you get comfortable with this model, take a look at `Cooperator` objects for more functionality.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am still trying to make it work but I think I need to read the twisted documentation first. This is not easy.